# How to make a WFS Layer read only in Geoserver?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, wfs

So I imported some postcode data into a Postgis table and published the layer using Geoserver.

As it is postcode data, there is absolutely no need for users to edit, so I would like to make the layer read only.

How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also switch off WFS-T for your service by going to the WMS menu page (Services->WMS) and changing the service level from `Complete` to `Basic`.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41448/discussion-on-answer-by-iant-how-to-make-a-wfs-layer-read-only-in-geoserver).

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways of achieving this:

- Use [Geoserver's Service Security](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/service.html#anonymous-wfs-access-only-for-read-only-operations)
- Connect to the PostGIS table with a user who only has Read-Only access on the Table.

Ideally you should do both.

Comment: I'm the only Postgis user but I think the Geoserver solution could do the trick, could you please tell me where to enter those lines of code? The Geoserver documentation isn't very clear on that

Comment: @Luffydude: I'll suggest that you go through this (http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/sysadmin/security/multiuser/index.html) for a detailed understanding of security for GeoServer